# How to customize CSS for a class inside an ID

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

**I need to apply a CSS on a class**

This is simple but, the same class is used multiple times inside my wordpress theme and i need to edit just one of them

i can use the #ID so, but i need a little help for the correct syntax

The Site URL is this http://news.ispazio.net/home-2/

i only want to change the 3 rectangles inside the "Block 1"

The class is from the `<li> "posts-items"</li>` and its css is:

```
.full-width .big-posts-box .posts-items li {
    width: calc(100% / 3);
    padding: 0 1.35%;
}
```

All this is inside an #ID which is `#tie-block_2099`

so, how do i correctly write the css that will change the `<li>` style only inside Block 1 and not in the other Blocks of the site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parent is `#tie-block_2099` which as also the class `.big-posts-box`. So this selector will only select the `li` inside of this block:

```css
#tie-block_2099 .posts-items li {
    /* custom styles */
}
```

Comment: pffff can't believe it was that simple -.-' 
Thank you very much! It worked

Comment: @fabiano1987 No problem ;) could you also please `upvote` my answer? :)

Answer (score 0):

if you want first 3 rectangle, try this

```
#tie-block_2884 .posts-items li:nth-child(n+1):nth-child(-n+3) {
    width: calc(100% / 3);
    padding: 0 1.35%;
}
```

It will get 1,2,3 li in the ul list.

```
:nth-child(n+X)     /* all children from the Xth position onward */
:nth-child(-n+x)    /* all children up to the Xth position       */
```

Comment: Thank you for the usefull explaination